# Sign String With RSA Public Key

Tags: python, rsa

Let's say I have generated private and public key RSA pair with this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

I have found this Python library which can use RSA key to sign a message:

http://stuvel.eu/files/python-rsa-doc/usage.html#signing-and-verification

It does not have methods to read the key from a file though. How can I do that?

Any other library you would recommend?

Basically, I want to sign all API requests coming from an app to my web service to make sure nobody else can use my APIs.

Answer (score 0):

ssh-keygen generates PEM files which can be accessed (according to the link you gave) like this:

```
$ cd ~/.ssh
$ python
>>> import rsa
>>> with open('id_rsa') as privatefile:
...     keydata = privatefile.read()
>>> privkey = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(keydata)
```